# fancybox make mousewheel fadeIn pics horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, mousewheel, fancybox-2

i use fancybox2 and have the mousewheel plugin integrated.
so now when using the mousewheel the images fadeIn vertically.

i would like to fadeIn the images horitzontally instead to emulate the next and prev buttons.

is there an option to enable this in fancybox?

or can i apply this behaviour from extern?

here is the init:

```
$('.thumbs .thumb .fancybox').fancybox({
            beforeShow: function(){
                $(".fancybox-skin").css("backgroundColor","transparent");
            }
 });
```

Comment: well im actually tearing apart the js file to see what i can do but making a request about this in github would be better. there is no such option as far as i see.

Comment: you are right its not featured yet:( https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/214 any hack possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found your solution

in your `jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js`

change this

```
 b.HORIZONTAL_AXIS && (g = 0, e = -1 * f);
```

to

```
 b.VERTICAL_AXIS && (g = 0, e = -1 * f);
```

AND for webkits change this

```
(e = -1 * b.wheelDeltaX / 120)
```

to

```
(e = -1 * b.wheelDeltaY / 120)
```

Here is a demonstration:

http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/TKxX3/

Comment: in the fiddle it still goes vertically, can it?

Comment: great! that works! thanks a lot for your efforts, much appreciated